# How to remove lines that match exact phrasse on Linux?

Tags: awk, sed

My file contains two lines with Unicode (probably) characters:

```
▒▒▒▒=

▒▒▒=
```

and I wish to remove both these lines from the file.

I searched and found I can use this command to remove non UTF-8 characters:

```
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii file
```

but it leaves those two lines like this:

```
=

=
```

I can't find how to remove lines that match (not just contain, but match) certain phrase, in my case: `=`.

UPDATE: i found that when i redirect the "=" lines to other file, and open the file, it contains unwanted line: ^A=
which i was unable to match with sed to delete it.

Comment: `grep -v '^whatever$' file` will remove lines that ARE `whatever`. Is that all you're looking for? If not then edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Could probably use `grep -vFx` (inverse match, fixed string and match whole line), then remove the anchors from the pattern.

Comment: @EdMorton using `grep` forces the user to create a new file. Using `sed` allows the user to replace "in place" without copying the -cleared- file. Ins't `sed` better then?

Comment: Depends what your criteria for `better` is. Only some seds allow "in place" editing and those have different arguments on different OSes for doing so so that functionality isn't portable. I suspect grep would be faster than sed since this is THE operation it's engineered to do. sed doesn't really do "in place" editing it just creates the temp file internally so all you can really says is that `sed -i '.bk' '/^whatever$/d' file` is a bit briefer than `grep -v '^whatever$' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. So is sed "better" - idk.

Comment: @Ed Morton - that "grep -v" kind of command do not works on special characters shown when you open file in "vim". when i redirect output of that command to a new file, and open using vim, i see line: ^A=  - when i then match for "A=" it finds nothing.

Comment: `A` is not `^A`. grep works fine you just have to make sure which characters you're asking it to find. Going forward - there's no such thing as a "special" character. There's control characters and maybe other types of characters that are invisible to some tools - just figure out what you're dealing with and then you'll be able to google an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\(\o342\o226\o222\)\+=/d' file
```

Use:

```
sed -n l file
```

To find the octal representation of the unicode characters and then use the `\o...` metacharacter in the regexp to match.

EDIT:

To remove the lines only containing `=` use:

```
sed '/^\(\o342\o226\o222\)\*=\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: The question of the post is "how to remove lines of a file that match '=', without any other character".

Comment: @Auzias you are right, I've amended the solution accordingly.

Comment: i meant it rather general, not just delete lines equal to "=". Example the line that i want to remove contains characters like: $ / : . , and so that not worked.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the command to clear these lines:

`sed -i 's/^=$//g' your_file`

As specify in the comment you can also use `grep -v '^whatever$' your_file > cleared_file`. Note that this solution required to set a different ouput (cleared_file) while the `sed`-solution allows you to modify the content "in place".

Comment: i think it may work, but i have a leftower line: ^A=  visible via vim, not via cat